# How to get rid of a portion of a string using regex

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

Used:

```
df['description'] = df['description'].str.replace(r'^[\d\s\-]*', '', regex=True)
```

to clean the data but that seems to have only gotten rid of numbers that started in the string. Currently the data has captured data not suppose to be there.

What is the best regex to clean this data? Looking to eliminate the 9-11.3 portion on the description

`df` looks like this:

```
   country  bound                                                          string
0    India   9.00  METEOROLOGICAL AIDS   5.54A 9-11.3 METEOROLOGICAL AIDS   5.54A
1    India   8.30  METEOROLOGICAL AIDS   5.54A 9-11.3 METEOROLOGICAL AIDS   5.54A
2    India   9.00  METEOROLOGICAL AIDS   5.54A 9-11.3 METEOROLOGICAL AIDS   5.54A
3    India   9.00             METEOROLOGICAL AIDS   5.54A RADIONAVIGATION 11.3-14
4    India  11.30             METEOROLOGICAL AIDS   5.54A RADIONAVIGATION 11.3-14
5    India   9.00             METEOROLOGICAL AIDS   5.54A RADIONAVIGATION 11.3-14
6    India  11.30             METEOROLOGICAL AIDS   5.54A RADIONAVIGATION 11.3-14
7    India  11.30                                                RADIONAVIGATION 
8    India  14.00                                                RADIONAVIGATION 
9    India  11.30                                                RADIONAVIGATION 
10   India  14.00                                                RADIONAVIGATION 
11   India  14.00                               FIXED MARITIME MOBILE   5.57 5.56
12   India  19.95                               FIXED MARITIME MOBILE   5.57 5.56
13   India  14.00                               FIXED MARITIME MOBILE   5.57 5.56
14   India  19.95                               FIXED MARITIME MOBILE   5.57 5.56
15   India  19.95            STANDARD FREQUENCY AND TIME SIGNAL (20 kHz) 20.05-70
16   India  20.05            STANDARD FREQUENCY AND TIME SIGNAL (20 kHz) 20.05-70
17   India  19.95            STANDARD FREQUENCY AND TIME SIGNAL (20 kHz) 20.05-70
18   India  20.05            STANDARD FREQUENCY AND TIME SIGNAL (20 kHz) 20.05-70
19   India  20.05                               FIXED MARITIME MOBILE   5.57 5.56
20   India  70.00                               FIXED MARITIME MOBILE   5.57 5.56
21   India  20.05                               FIXED MARITIME MOBILE   5.57 5.56
22   India  70.00                               FIXED MARITIME MOBILE   5.57 5.56
23   India  70.00             RADIONAVIGATION   5.60 Fixed Maritime mobile   5.57
24   India  72.00             RADIONAVIGATION   5.60 Fixed Maritime mobile   5.57
25   India  70.00             RADIONAVIGATION   5.60 Fixed Maritime mobile   5.57
26   India  72.00             RADIONAVIGATION   5.60 Fixed Maritime mobile   5.57
27   India  72.00             FIXED MARITIME MOBILE   5.57 RADIONAVIGATION   5.60
28   India  84.00             FIXED MARITIME MOBILE   5.57 RADIONAVIGATION   5.60
29   India  72.00             FIXED MARITIME MOBILE   5.57 RADIONAVIGATION   5.60
30   India  84.00             FIXED MARITIME MOBILE   5.57 RADIONAVIGATION   5.60
31   India  84.00             RADIONAVIGATION   5.60 Fixed Maritime mobile   5.57
32   India  86.00             RADIONAVIGATION   5.60 Fixed Maritime mobile   5.57
33   India  84.00             RADIONAVIGATION   5.60 Fixed Maritime mobile   5.57
34   India  86.00             RADIONAVIGATION   5.60 Fixed Maritime mobile   5.57
```

Input df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'country': ['India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India', 'India'],
     'bound': [9.0, 8.3, 9.0, 9.0, 11.3, 9.0, 11.3, 11.3, 14.0, 11.3, 14.0, 14.0, 19.95, 14.0, 19.95, 19.95, 20.05, 19.95, 20.05, 20.05, 70.0, 20.05, 70.0, 70.0, 72.0, 70.0, 72.0, 72.0, 84.0, 72.0, 84.0, 84.0, 86.0, 84.0, 86.0],
     'string': ['METEOROLOGICAL AIDS   5.54A 9-11.3 METEOROLOGICAL AIDS   5.54A',
                'METEOROLOGICAL AIDS   5.54A 9-11.3 METEOROLOGICAL AIDS   5.54A',
                'METEOROLOGICAL AIDS   5.54A 9-11.3 METEOROLOGICAL AIDS   5.54A',
                'METEOROLOGICAL AIDS   5.54A RADIONAVIGATION 11.3-14',
                'METEOROLOGICAL AIDS   5.54A RADIONAVIGATION 11.3-14',
                'METEOROLOGICAL AIDS   5.54A RADIONAVIGATION 11.3-14',
                'METEOROLOGICAL AIDS   5.54A RADIONAVIGATION 11.3-14',
                'RADIONAVIGATION ',
                'RADIONAVIGATION ',
                'RADIONAVIGATION ',
                'RADIONAVIGATION ',
                'FIXED MARITIME MOBILE   5.57 5.56',
                'FIXED MARITIME MOBILE   5.57 5.56',
                'FIXED MARITIME MOBILE   5.57 5.56',
                'FIXED MARITIME MOBILE   5.57 5.56',
                'STANDARD FREQUENCY AND TIME SIGNAL (20 kHz) 20.05-70',
                'STANDARD FREQUENCY AND TIME SIGNAL (20 kHz) 20.05-70',
                'STANDARD FREQUENCY AND TIME SIGNAL (20 kHz) 20.05-70',
                'STANDARD FREQUENCY AND TIME SIGNAL (20 kHz) 20.05-70',
                'FIXED MARITIME MOBILE   5.57 5.56',
                'FIXED MARITIME MOBILE   5.57 5.56',
                'FIXED MARITIME MOBILE   5.57 5.56',
                'FIXED MARITIME MOBILE   5.57 5.56',
                'RADIONAVIGATION   5.60 Fixed Maritime mobile   5.57',
                'RADIONAVIGATION   5.60 Fixed Maritime mobile   5.57',
                'RADIONAVIGATION   5.60 Fixed Maritime mobile   5.57',
                'RADIONAVIGATION   5.60 Fixed Maritime mobile   5.57',
                'FIXED MARITIME MOBILE   5.57 RADIONAVIGATION   5.60',
                'FIXED MARITIME MOBILE   5.57 RADIONAVIGATION   5.60',
                'FIXED MARITIME MOBILE   5.57 RADIONAVIGATION   5.60',
                'FIXED MARITIME MOBILE   5.57 RADIONAVIGATION   5.60',
                'RADIONAVIGATION   5.60 Fixed Maritime mobile   5.57',
                'RADIONAVIGATION   5.60 Fixed Maritime mobile   5.57',
                'RADIONAVIGATION   5.60 Fixed Maritime mobile   5.57',
                'RADIONAVIGATION   5.60 Fixed Maritime mobile   5.57']}
```

[image]

Comment: please add a little sample of your dataframe to your question as text (not as image)

Comment: Do you want to remove the `11.3-14` as well? What about the numbers in `FIXED MARITIME MOBILE   5.57 5.56`?

Comment: No just delete 9-11.3 and any other string that come after that. so  9-11.3 METEOROLOGICAL AIDS   5.54A would be deleted but nothing before that in the first line.

Comment: So the line `METEOROLOGICAL AIDS   5.54A RADIONAVIGATION 11.3-14` would not be changed?

Comment: Sorry misunderstood. Yes 11.3-14 would be removed but FIXED MARITIME MOBILE   5.57 5.56 would stay

Comment: sorry, your goal is still not quite clear to me. In this whole dataframe, only the first 3 rows should be changed? and the change should be: leave everything before 9-11.3, and remove everything after it including 9-11.3?

Comment: @George, Good that you have posted your efforts. Kindly do add your expected output samples in text form in your question, if you want to edit by regex las column only then you can put in expected output only last column but put it in text please so that it will be clear to us, Thank you.

Comment: @Rabinzel There are hundred of rows like the 9-11.3 example. Only showed an example of the issue. The goal is to remove 9-11.3 and all the strings that come after that in that particular row. All other rows that have the same issue I would like to clean out as well. I haven't able to figure out how to do this at scale

Comment: Please show the expected output for your sample (your intention is still not clear enough).